# Processing MongoDB in AWS EMR with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, emr, mrjob, mongodb-hadoop

I'm trying to do a map reduce using mrjob and Python against a MongoDB database. 
The mongodb-hadoop connector has examples on how to use AWS EMR but not with mrjob, and I'm not quite getting all the bits together. Here is what I have already as far as a mrjob.conf goes:

```
    enable_emr_debugging: true
    ami_version: 3.0.4
    interpreter: python2.7

    upload_files:
    - tweets-clean.txt
    - train_model.py

    python_archives:
    - mrcc.py.tar.gz

    setup:
    #- python2.7 train_model.py

    jobconf:
        mongo.job.input.format : com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat
        mongo.input.uri : myserver:27017/twitter_db
        stream.io.identifier.resolver : com.mongodb.streaming.io.MongoIdentifierResolver


    bootstrap:
        - sudo yum --releasever=2014.09 install -y python27 python27-devel gcc-c++ numpy scipy
        - sudo python2.7 get-pip.py#
        - sudo pip2.7 install boto mrjob simplejson scikit-learn sklearn pymongo-hadoop
        - python2.7 train_model.py# tweets-clean.txt#
        - mongo-hadoop-bootstrap.sh#
```

When using mrjob Python mapper/reducers I've used code like this:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, line):
    words=line.split()
    for word in words:
        yield word, 1

def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

To modify this to use the mongodb-hadoop connecter, I'm trying to do this:

```
from pymongo_hadoop import BSONMapper
from pymongo_hadoop import BSONReducer
from mrjob.job import MRJob
class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, documents):
    BSONMapper(self.bsonmapper)

def reducer(self, key, values):
    BSONReducer(self.bsonreducer)

def bsonmapper(documents):
    for doc in documents:
        yield {'_id' : doc['id']['user.id']}, {'count' : 1}

def bsonreducer(self, key, values):
    count = 0
    for v in values:
        count += v['count']
    return {'_id' : key, 'count' : count}       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

The problem is that I'm not passing the methods to the BSONMapper and BSONReducer correctly. The BSONMapper class expects 1 argument in the **init**() but it's getting 2.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Please provide more detail as to exactly what isn't working. Stack Overflow is for getting help with your code, not getting people to write code for you.

Comment: Apologies, late night. I modified the class in the original post that I'm trying to use. I need to pass the BSONMapper() and BSONReducer() a method, but they are getting two parameters, probably self and the method. I've tried making the bsonmapper() and bsonreducer() external functions to the class and throws a ValueError: could lose data exception.

Comment: I've moved the bsonmapper() and bsonreducer() out of the class and that solves one problem, but now I get an Python error: ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: Could you ever solve this problem? I currently try to save the mrjob output to mongodb but the process hangs between step1 and 2 . Sadly no log stating a problem.